# Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\main.html'

Tags: angularjs, express

I am trying to run a sample angular app using the node js:
Below is the code in the file server.js:

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
app 
   .use(express.static('./public'))
   .get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('public/main.html');
})
   .listen(3000);
```

But I am getting the below error:
`Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\main.html'`

My folder structure:

```
C:\Users\kk\Documents\angularWork\PracticeWork\contacts\public
C:\Users\kk\Documents\angularWork\PracticeWork\contacts\public\main.html
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\main.html'
```

Comment: I have seen using the link:file:///C:/Users/kk/Documents/angularWork/PracticeWork/contacts/public/main.html   I am able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `main.html` file doesn't exists.
Locate your console in the folder where the files are located, or as alternative move the folder `C:\Users\kk\Documents\angularWork\PracticeWork\contacts\public` under `C:\`